# On clicking Show Application in docker start hanging

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gtk3

I changes my theme by following youtube video. Now after changing theme my app launcher has started freezing and hanging and also background image has became fuzzy and so to reset i have executed

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
```

then also its freesing after clicking on show app or pressing window button.

- This is the image of desktop which is working fine.
  [image: Desktop]

  - This is the activity window where its started freezing also background image is not appearing proper also same happens in application listing.
    [image: Application]

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer i reset whole gnome by

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```